# Audio but no video when playing a movie using mediaplayerelement in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player

I am trying to use MediaPlayerElement in a WPF to play streaming videos. I have set up a simple WPF window that contains a MediaPlayerElement instance and auto-plays a video. When I run the program, I can hear audio but the video is not visible.

I started by following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/mediaplayerelement 
Unfortunately the tutorial appears to be out of date, as it no longer works. I made a few corrections to get it to a running state, but cannot get the video to appear.

I have tried placing the MediaPlayerElement inside a Grid or StackPanel, but can't because it is not a UIElement.

```
<Window x:Class="MediaPlayerElement_Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MediaPlayerElement_Test"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

  <controls:MediaPlayerElement Name="mediaPlayerElement"  AutoScaleDimensions="800,450"
    Source="https://mediaplatstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/windows-universal-samples-media/elephantsdream-clip-h264_sd-aac_eng-aac_spa-aac_eng_commentary-srt_eng-srt_por-srt_swe.mkv"
    AutoPlay="True" Anchor="Top" Height="450" Width="800"  AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" />

</Window>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? How do I get the video to display in the window?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, this works perfectly for me

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Media"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Media" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Margin="10,10,10,0 " Source="http://mediaplatstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/windows-universal-samples-media/elephantsdream-clip-h264_sd-aac_eng-aac_spa-aac_eng_commentary-srt_eng-srt_por-srt_swe.mkv"
                          Name="McMediaElement"
             Width="450" Height="250" LoadedBehavior="Play"  UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Grid>
```

if this is not working then it might be the issue with your video codec